# Register client script at Timer's Tick event

Tags: c#

I'm trying to register script at timer's tick event but nothing is happening,

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", "ShowDialog()", true);
        }
```

Tried `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` as well but it's not working. Tried calling simple alert but not working as well.

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you get inside the Tick method?

Comment: @ToonCasteele No error, Yes it goes inside Tick method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegisterClientScriptBlock will only work when a page first loads up.  You can't possibly expect it to work when being called on a background thread on the server.

You instead need to register a client script block that initiates a timer client side - look at javascript setTimeout.

e.g. in the page load

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", "window.setTimeout(ShowDialog, 1000);", true);
```

or with arguments...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", "window.setTimeout(function(){ShowDialog(arg1,arg2);}, 1000);", true);
```

Comment: So now way to executes some client JS in tick event along side C# codes ?

Comment: The C# tick event will fire after the page has already been served up to the client browser, so you cannot then change what is in the browser.

Comment: Tried your approach but there is an error says "
Error: ReferenceError: ShowDialog is not defined
Source File: url Line: 452"

Comment: Ah, yes, take off the parentheses on ShowDialog() (see update above)

Comment: What if the function takes argument, like ShowDialog(arg1,arg2) ?