# Register client script block won't play audio in timer tick handle in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

In Visual Studio's ASP.NET I want to play audio in response to a timer's tick handle method like this code below.

```
int i = 0;
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   i = (int)ViewState["i"];
   PlayArpeggio(i);
   i++;
   ViewState["i"] = i;
}

private void PlayArpeggio(int i)
{
 if (i == 3)
   {
          ClientScriptManager clientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript;
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.Append("<script language='Javascript'>");
          sb.Append("function PlayArpeggioTwo()  {");  
          sb.Append("document.getElementById('arpeggioTwo').play();");
          sb.Append("}");
          sb.Append("PlayArpeggioTwo();");
          sb.Append("<");
          sb.Append("/script>");

              if(!clientScriptManager.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JackpotSound"))
              {
               clientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"JackpotSound",sb.ToString());           
              }
   }
}
```

But it wont play the sound.  The above code works fine with all other things that I include in the timer tick sub methods(based on incrementing 'i' each time). Of course the timer is inside an 'update panel'. I don't know if that is shielding the script from playing. And, is there a better way than this altogether?

Thanks
John

Comment: I have been working on the audio element of my project for a few months. I have tried several approaches.  Most of the problem is with the page refresh(post-back) having all of the control, and not being able to control the audio with the C# 'code-behind'.  It is in the code-behind where I want to direct the play of these short sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I needed JavaScript to play audio in response to the code behind events such as an 'asp:button's' click event, as well as, an 'asp:timer's' tick event. But, as the advice suggested, the JavaScript in a file or on the html page can't seem to hear (respond to) these 'code behind' events. The JavaScript is responding only to page refreshes, not the distinct events themselves.  So the work-around for me was to register script behind the asp:button's click event and also to establish a JavaScript timer to execute JavaScript code, all to play the audio on the conditions desired.

However, if I had used the On Client Click attribute in the button element, then this would have gone far to address my question.

Sources that helped me address my own question include:
[Register Client Script at Timer's Tick Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113322/register-client-script-at-timers-tick-event)
[Window Clear Timeout Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)